# Request em API do grafana com PHP

Tags: php, api, http-request

Estou tentando criar um arquivo PHP que faz autenticação direta no [GRAFANA](https://grafana.com/) e exibe a DASHBOARD na minha página, porém não está exibindo nada com a estrutura abaixo:

```
<?php

//Server url
$url = "http://meu-ip/api/dashboards/home";
$apiKey = 'aqui-vem-a-chave'; // should match with Server key
$headers = array(
     'Authorization: Bearer '.$apiKey
);
// Send request to Server
$ch = curl_init($url);
// To save response in a variable from server, set headers;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// Get response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// Decode
$result = json_decode($response);

?>
```

Eu criei uma [API KEY](https://grafana.com/docs/http_api/auth/) no grafana para fazer essa autenticação.

Comment: ve se o problema não é adicionar um **curl_close($ch)**; antes do $result

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\front-end\teste.php on line 18

Comment: Retornou o erro acima

Comment: se eu coloco um print_r(), sem o curl_close($ch), em $result, a saída é: stdClass Object ( [redirectUri] => /d/hc63X9VZz/menu-automation )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testa dessa forma colocando sua chave da api no lugar do KEY_API do $authorization

```
  //Server url
    $url = "http://meu-ip/api/dashboards/home";
    $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer KEY_API";

    // Send request to Server
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $jsonDecode = json_decode($result);
```

Comment: Fiz as aleterações, obtive a seguinte saída: Notice: Undefined variable: post in C:\xampp\htdocs\front-end\teste.php on line 12

Comment: modifiquei agora, coloquei sem querer o $post

Comment: Não me retornou nenhum erro, dei um print na variável $result, e me retornou isso: {"message":"Not found"}

Comment: você tbm pode trocar **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");** por **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");** isso se a requisição por GET msm